# automatically name dataframe based on file name

Tags: r

If I observe a convention of saving my file paths as variables with the common prefix "file_", it seems I could create a wrapper function for `read_rds()` that would name my read files based on whatever text came after "file_" in the file path's name.

I run into trouble when I evaluate the name I want the read file to take.

```
library(here)
library(readr)
library(stringr)

file_survey <- here("my_survey_2019.rds")

my_read_rds <- function(file){
  name <- deparse(substitute(file))
  name <- stringr::str_remove(name, "^file_")
  eval(name) <- readr::read_rds(file) # Does not work
}

my_read_rds(file_survey) # would ideally create a dataframe named `survey`
```

Comment: This type of behavior isn't encouraged in R. Functions shouldn't have "side effects" or create variables outside their scope. The "normal" way to do this is `survey <- read_rds(file)`. This makes functions much easier to deal with and to be called from inside other functions.

Comment: that is a good point

Comment: @MrFlick "Side effect" is a functional programming terminology, but it's not the only way to program in R.  For example, `data.table` does not follow a functional programming paradigm, yet it's one of the most popular libraries.  People should program the way that they want to, if it makes sense to them or if they have a system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign`.

```
my_read_rds <- function(file){
  name <- deparse(substitute(file))
  name <- stringr::str_remove(name, "^file_")
  assign(name, readr::read_rds(file), envir=globalenv())
}
```